# Adding an (to be) created object to a method

Tags: java, class, object, parameters

I have a question regarding adding an (to be) created object to a method.

So I have this ticket class where I set every user to a particular seat, it uses an Integer of Seat and a Class 'User'. That is working alright, but now I want use this method in the 'User' class, but in the parameter it uses a parameter of user. So in the 'user' class I need to define the name of the object itself, so if a user creates the user object, how can I define it's name that the user created?

I hope you understand what I writing, it's a little bit hard for me to explain it.

TICKET CLASS

```
//User assignments
public void assignUser(User user){
    this.user.put(user, seat);
    this.seatofuser.put(seat, user);
}
```

USER CLASS

```
public void assignToTicket(){
    this.ticket.assignUser();
}
```

thanks,

MrJFK

Comment: It's a little difficult to follow you, but I think all you're trying to do is pass 'this' to the assignUser() method. So `this.ticket.assignUser(this);`

Comment: You may want to add the full code here. Where is seat, seatofuser, ticket defined? That said, I believe you will be better off stating the requirements without mentions of the classes as your OO modeling might not be correct.

Comment: Your `User` class should accept parameter of `Ticket`/`Seat`, it is already aware of itself.